# How can I get to String "no comm" instead of null value using pandas in python ?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I get to string  "no comm" instead of  null value using pandas ?

emp.csv

```
index   empno   ename   job mgr hiredate    sal comm    deptno
0,  7839,   KING,   PRESIDENT,  0,  1981-11-17,     5000,    ,  10
1,  7698,   BLAKE,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-01, 2850,    ,  30
2,  7782,   CLARK,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-09, 2450,    ,  10
3,  7566,   JONES,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-04-01, 2975,    ,  20
4,  7654,   MARTIN, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-09-10, 1250,   1400,   30
5,  7499,   ALLEN,  SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-11, 1600,    300,    30
6,  7844,   TURNER, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-08-21, 1500,   0,  30
7,  7900,   JAMES,  CLERK,      7698,   1981-12-11, 950,     ,  30
8,  7521,   WARD,   SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-23, 1250,   500,    30
9,  7902,   FORD,   ANALYST,    7566,   1981-12-11, 3000,    ,  20
10, 7369,   SMITH,  CLERK,      7902,   1980-12-09, 800,     ,  20
11, 7788,   SCOTT,  ANALYST,    7566,    1982-12-22, 3000,   ,  20
12, 7876,   ADAMS,  CLERK,      7788,   1983-01-15, 1100,    ,  20
13, 7934,   MILLER, CLERK,      7782,   1982-01-11, 1300,    ,  10
```

I want to get the below result  about column comm using  pandas.

result :

```
no comm
no comm
no comm
no comm
1400
300
0
no comm
500
no comm
no comm
no comm
no comm
no comm
```

I want to get  above  result  using  bleow  code.

code :

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
import dateutil



import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""index   empno   ename   job mgr hiredate    sal comm    deptno
0,  7839,   KING,   PRESIDENT,  0,  1981-11-17,     5000,    ,  10
1,  7698,   BLAKE,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-01, 2850,    ,  30
2,  7782,   CLARK,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-05-09, 2450,    ,  10
3,  7566,   JONES,  MANAGER,    7839,   1981-04-01, 2975,    ,  20
4,  7654,   MARTIN, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-09-10, 1250,   1400,   30
5,  7499,   ALLEN,  SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-11, 1600,    300,    30
6,  7844,   TURNER, SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-08-21, 1500,   0,  30
7,  7900,   JAMES,  CLERK,      7698,   1981-12-11, 950,     ,  30
8,  7521,   WARD,   SALESMAN,   7698,   1981-02-23, 1250,   500,    30
9,  7902,   FORD,   ANALYST,    7566,   1981-12-11, 3000,    ,  20
10, 7369,   SMITH,  CLERK,      7902,   1980-12-09, 800,     ,  20
11, 7788,   SCOTT,  ANALYST,    7566,    1982-12-22, 3000,   ,  20
12, 7876,   ADAMS,  CLERK,      7788,   1983-01-15, 1100,    ,  20
13, 7934,   MILLER, CLERK,      7782,   1982-01-11, 1300,    ,  10"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
emp = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                 skipinitialspace=True,
                 skiprows=1, 
                 parse_dates=[5], 
                 names=['index','empno','ename', 'job','mgr','hiredate','sal','comm','deptno'])


                                               <--------------  ?  


print( emp['comm'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could just be the formatting on this site, but it looks like 1400, 300, 0 and 500 are in a different level of indentation to the rest of the numbers, which is why it would return no comm

Comment: Your answer is right. The result of code in this site is below.
{0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4     1400.0
5      300.0
6        0.0
7        NaN
8      500.0
9        NaN
10       NaN
11       NaN
12       NaN
13       NaN}